# How to add all close rgb values together

Tags: python, sorting, rgb

I want to add all rgb values that are close

Example:

```py
rgb = [(0, 0, 78),(0, 254, 255),(255, 30, 90),(255, 0, 60),(106,190,30),(21,30,28),(0,0,0)]
```

Output:

```py
blue = [((0, 0, 78),(0, 254, 255),]
pink = [(255, 30, 90),(255, 0, 60),]
green = [(106,190,30)]
gray = [(21,30,28)]
black = [(0,0,0)]
```

and i want to have the ability to make the range/difference like to be in the same color it must be lower than or equal a 10 shade difference

And then i want to add them to a dictionary as keys and values in this format:

```py
rgb = {"blue":(All the rgb values in the list blue,ect...}
```

All automatic

Comment: First you need to determine for each RGB value which color it is. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: How do you define a "10 shade difference"?

Comment: It might be helpful to convert the RGB to HSV.

Comment: Ok, but what are you planning to do with the answer?

Comment: @mkrieger1 no, and i define it as like blue can have all blue in the list in the range of the 10 closest shades to blue but like it automatically does it in the list it looks through the list the first value like 0,0,0 gets checked with all other values and the 10 closest shades to it get put in a list with it, and it does that with every value

Answer (score 1):

Colour comparisons really depend on what you mean by being 'nearly the same'. Where I need to compare colours in some way I find conversion to HSV is useful. Instead of colours being represented as intensities of colour components, it is represented as Hue, Saturation, Value. Hue is the colour, Saturation is how intense the colour is and Value is how bright it is. Look for a function that does this conversion, and there are plenty of code snippets available for this.

With HSV you can more easily group colours together. You can try doing a *weighted average* of all three with the weights indicating the importance of each of the three attributes. With a single number you can then easily group them.